# How to solve performance entry type FP and FCP problem in Firefox and Safari?

Tags: firefox, safari, web-performance, performance-measuring

It seems Firefox and Safari has a problem with or even not supporting performance entry types "first-paint" and "first-contentful-paint". **What is the alternative way to handle these metrics?**

Error in Firefox

[image]

Safari Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right now we are putting a mark in the start of our HTML and another one in last line of body tag using performance.mark. Then we are measuring duration between this two marks with performance.measure.
Maybe there is a better way to handle that.

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <script>
        performance.mark('started');


<script>
    performance.mark('first-contentful-paint');
</script>
</body>
```